# Checking if GPS location is inside an area of Google Maps/My Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, mymaps

I am searching for a possibility to check whether a GPS location is inside a certain custom created area preferably created in Google My Maps from Google Maps.

I have created an area in Google My Maps:

[image: Google My Maps area]

Getting the GPS coordinates isn't a big deal, but how can I compare, whether it is inside the selected area? I have read about the possibility to check whether it is within a radius, but not a exact area.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the containsLocation method provided by Maps Javascript API.

Pass the marker and polygon to the function and it will return a message stating whether marker is inside or outside the polygon. You can customize the function as per your need.

```
function isMarkerInPolygon(marker, polygon){
    var message = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(marker.latLng, polygon) ?
              'Inside Polygon' :
              'Outside Polygon';
    return message;
}
```

If you are using it in Android you can use the `PolyUtil.containsLocation` method from the Google Maps Android API Utility Library. 
This answer should be helpful : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41203381